# Component height not rendering properly with Flex box

Tags: css, flexbox, react-native

I am trying to create a MapView component using React Native and have given it the following styling:

```
map: {
    flex: 1,
    width: vw,
    height: vh,
}
```

The component is to render completely between a navbar and a footer.

How do I get the Map to render with 100% height between the navbar and footer?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `calc()` in the css.

for exapmle, if your header is **50px** high you would set the map `height: calc(100% - 50px;)`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/3oo2jmko/2/

Comment: This gave a parser error in React Native. May have to do with jsx but it did not work

Comment: Thanks for putting that together -- I understand the solution, but it seems there is a syntax parser conflict that is occuring with the jsx

Comment: I don't know what jsx is, so it probably is the issue, add jsx to your tags to help refine your question so that people who know jsx can help ya out.